# 3 lines of code, one causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios

I have an array that I want to populate with a dictionary, however I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to view the pickerView that is populated with the array. One of these 3 lines of code causes it.

```
paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) copy];
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
  NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fullArray.plist"];
```

Full Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fullArray.plist"];

dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
array = [dictionary allKeys];

[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

}

Comment: Please post the code which uses the arrays. This code tells us nothing. Some of these are not retained by default, but that might or might not matter depending on how you're using them. Also, what do you see in the debugger when the crash occur?

Comment: "One of these three lines" tells us nothing. Are you using ARC?

Comment: No, I disabled it because it interfered with other sections of my code.

Comment: NSZombies tells me, An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x6d52c50.

Comment: It says it's been released, but where?

Comment: Which array does the pickerView get its data from? "array"? If so, it's not retained, which could be a problem. As for the zombie, does that address match any of the objects in this method or the method which returns data to the pickerView?

Comment: Find out which line exacty causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The Zombie should give you a hint of what data type/class name your released object is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the NSArray returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains is becoming a Zombie. You could try getting a copy of it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) copy];
```

Comment: Hang on, no it's not sorry, it's happening again. Instruments says it's the Array though...

Comment: Bah! Did it work at least once? Is this an intermittent problem?

Comment: How would I write that line so it was retained?

Comment: `NSArray *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) retain];`

Comment: You know you can disable ARC on a per-file basis by adding a compiler flag to each compilable source [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). Maybe using ARC for most of your project (and disabling only the files that are being interfered with) would help?

Comment: I've reenabled ARC, and added the retained code but it still crashes.

Comment: # Address Category Event Type RefCt Timestamp Size Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0 0x6d51810 __NSArrayI Malloc 1 00:18.271.594 48 QuickConfig -[SecondViewController viewDidLoad]
1 0x6d51810 __NSArrayI Autorelease <null> 00:18.271.654 0 QuickConfig -[SecondViewController viewDidLoad]
2 0x6d51810 __NSArrayI Release 0 00:18.714.209 0 Foundation -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
3 0x6d51810 __NSArrayI Zombie -1 00:18.947.685 0 QuickConfig -[SecondViewController pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:]

Comment: The issue is in the pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, with this line, you're trying to save a value into an ivar named "arrays":

```
array = [dictionary allKeys];
```

But that's not going to work (unless it's and ARC project, which you say it isn't).

You need to retain that value. Make array a property that's retained (or copied). Or (not quite as good) retain it yourself:

```
[array autorelease];  // Don't skip this, or it may leak.
array = [[dictionary allKeys] retain];
```